# how to send a sub buffer to server by nodejs + axios

Tags: node.js, buffer

I want send a part of bigFile to serve by pure nodejs+axios+form-data.
nodejs v16.14.0

but I don't know how to send buffer direct to server

```js
import FormData from 'form-data'

const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
const chunk = buffer.slice(start, end)

// some code ...

// below code can work
// but the way need write file to disk
fs.writeFileSync(chunkPath, chunk)
formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(chunkPath))
// end below code can work

// below code doesn't work
import { Readable } from 'stream'
formData.append('file', Readable.from(chunk).read())
```

dont's save buffer to disk, and send to server

Comment: Try adding a name to see if it work, eg `formData.append('file', Readable.from(chunk).read(), 'video.mp4.1')`